# Does it make sense to test for nonlinear moderation if my independent variable is insignificant?

Tags: regression, least-squares, nonlinear, interaction

Currently doing an OLS regression in Stata. I have 2 independent variables(also included square terms), dummy variables and 1 moderator variable. However, to the best of my knowledge, I have to include the interaction term + squared interaction term (nonlinear moderation). One of the independent variables is not significant (first and second degree), does it then make sense to have an interaction effect between this variable and my moderator variable?

This is the first time doing such a regression, so it's all a bit confusing for me!